# Is this a potential issue? Facebook accessToken in plain text

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK to authenticate users, although I cannot use Session Variables via Facebook due to 3rd party cookie issue, ie Session State does not work in an iFrame.

To get around this I redirect between pages using POST's where I create a form and post the accessToken which I use on the server to authenticate.

When I redirect I have the accessToken in the ViewModel and have this written out into javascript, ie doing a viewSource will show the accessToken. Is this the incorrect way of doing it?

SHould I rather get a new accessToken via FB.getLoginStatus / FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) [I currentle use a combination of both] and post that to the views (which I then re authenticate server side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access token in plain text sounds like a big risk to me.  Especially if you are using JS SDK because someone could get your APPID from your javascript source and along with the access token that's all they need to start performing graph actions.

I'm pretty sure that if you just re-authenticate the user every time using the FB JS SDK (as you suggested at the end) that you'll get the same access token anyway, so no need to pass it around.  Test it out yourself and I bet you'll see the same access token.

You might want to take a look at how Facebook themselves handle this.  The [Facebook PHP SDK on github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) supports authentication between the client (JS SDK) and the server.  I believe they are using a combination of cookies and PHP secure sessions to pass the access token around, but you'd have to look closer at the source code yourself to figure out exactly how they are doing it.

Comment: ok thanks, I am now getting the access token from FB JS SDK on each page load, so its in a JS variable, then moving between pages doing a post and verifying the accessToken in the view. (very similar to the example here: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started) can a user not see this accessToken in Firebug or other tool? ie which is in the same SDK example?

Comment: Yes the user could see their own access token.  That's ok.  What you want to prevent is other users intercepting that access token.

Comment: I don't think the example you gave is secure.  I've updated the answer with a pointer to how Facebook does this securely.